# Why createAsyncThunk doesn't pass through extraArgument type?

Tags: typescript, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I have a Redux store with an extra argument for thunk middleware configured according to [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware#customizing-the-included-middleware). That extra argument contains axios instance which I want to access from my thunks.

This example works, but passing extraArgument type explicitly for every thunk is annoying. Also I have to get rid of the dependency between store and slice, to move slice (as a part of a feature) to a shareable library. What's the right approach here?

```js
//store.ts
const store = configureStore({
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => {
    return getDefaultMiddleware({
      thunk: {
        extraArgument: { axiosInstance }
      },
    })
  },
  reducer: rootReducer,
});

//devices.ts
interface ExtraArgument {
  extra: {
    serviceApi: AxiosInstance;
  };
}

interface FetchResultFromServer {
  count: number;
  entities: Device[];
}

export const fetchDevices = createAsyncThunk<FetchResultFromServer, void, ExtraArgument>(
  'devices',
  async (args, { extra }) => {
    const { serviceApi } = extra;
    const response = await serviceApi.get('/devices');
    return response.data;
  }
);
```